# iPhone Mapkit: How can I get a real business name/address from a longitude/latitude?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, mapkit

I'm writing an iPhone application and trying to determine how to find a business name/address from a user's current GPS location (longitude/latitude). For example, if someone if using the application from inside a Starbucks, how can I find this out from their location? Is there a way to do this using mapkit or any API/Webservice?

Answer (score 2):

You can do this with [MKReverseGeocoder](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/mapkit/mkreversegeocoder) by providing a [MKReverseGeocoderDelegate](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/mapkit/mkreversegeocoderdelegate). It's actually quite simple.

The delegate will give you all sorts of information as an [MKPlacemark](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/mapkit/mkplacemark).

Answer (score 0):

You can get an address (MKReverseGeocoder), but you can't get a business name using the iPhone native SDK. I believe that both Google and Bing provide APIs for this, but one that I like to use (and it may have the most momentum) is Foursquare's.